# Get final HTML content after javascript finished by Open Webkit Sharp

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, open-webkit-sharp

I'm writing a software that gets the content from URL. When working on that, I run into to problem that I can not get exactly the HTML content after the java script finished. 
There are some websites that renders HTML by java-script, some do not support browsers which does not run js.

I tried using `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` with `WebBrowser.Document` in `LoadCompleted` but no luck.

After that, I tried the OpenWebkitSharp library. On the UI, it showes the content of website correctly, but with code `Document` in `DocumentCompleted`, it still returns the content which does not rendered by java-script.
Here is my code:

```cs
...
using WebKit;
using WebKit.Interop;

public MainWindow()
{
  windowFormHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
  webBrowser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
  webBrowser.AllowDownloads = false;
  windowFormHost.Child = webBrowser;
  grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(windowFormHost);
  webBrowser.Load += WebBrowser_Load;
}

private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  var contentHtml = ((WebKitBrowser)sender).DocumentAsHTMLDocument;
}
```

The contentHtml has value which is not rendered after java-script finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do solve this problem, I have added some trick into my code to get the full Html content after java-script finished.

```cs
using WebKit;
using WebKit.Interop;
using WebKit.JSCore; //We need add refrence JSCore which following with Webkit package.

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitBrowser();
}

private void InitBrowser()
{
  windowFormHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
  webBrowser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
  webBrowser.AllowDownloads = false;
  windowFormHost.Child = webBrowser;
  grdBrowserHost.Children.Add(windowFormHost);
  webBrowser.Load += WebBrowser_Load; 
}

private void WebBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //The ResourceIntercepter will throws exception if webBrowser have not finished loading its components
  //We can not use DocumentCompleted to load the Htmlcontent. Because that event will be fired before Java-script is finised
  webBrowser.ResourceIntercepter.ResourceFinishedLoadingEvent += new ResourceFinishedLoadingHandler(ResourceIntercepter_ResourceFinishedLoadingEvent);
}

private void ResourceIntercepter_ResourceFinishedLoadingEvent(object sender, WebKitResourcesEventArgs e)
{
   //The WebBrowser.Document still show the html without java-script. 
   //The trict is call Javascript (I used Jquery) to get the content of HTML
   JSValue documentContent = null;
   var readyState = webBrowser.GetScriptManager.EvaluateScript("document.readyState");

   if (readyState != null && readyState.ToString().Equals("complete"))
            {
                documentContent = webBrowser.GetScriptManager.EvaluateScript("$('html').html();");
                var contentHtml = documentContent.ToString();
            }

}
```

Hope this one can help you.